# adding namespace to xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have classes full of xpaths that now needs a specfic namespace.  How can I accomplish this?  What would be the easiest way to refactor this code?  find replace?

What would be the best way to grab specific nodes in the future, if I don't know the namespaces ahead of time?

```
susr1 = root.SelectSingleNode("/PurchaseOrderRequest/DocumentHeader/DocumentInformation/DocumentIdentification/Type");

susr1 = root.SelectSingleNode("/PurchaseOrderRequest/ssdh:DocumentHeader/ssdh:DocumentInformation/ssdh:DocumentIdentification/ssdh:Type");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [XML Library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/).  Use `XPathElement()`.  This is a .Net 3.5 solution if you can use it.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file) or .Parse(string)
```

Then either of your xpath's should work as long as there are not conflicting nodes with the same name (but different namespaces).

```
XElement susr1 = root.XPathElement("/PurchaseOrderRequest/DocumentHeader/DocumentInformation/DocumentIdentification/Type");

XElement susr1 = root.XPathElement("/PurchaseOrderRequest/ssdh:DocumentHeader/ssdh:DocumentInformation/ssdh:DocumentIdentification/ssdh:Type");
```

The library should figure out the namespace for you.  I cannot test it without example xml to be sure.